# console.log returns "undefined" though I created a new property(key) in the object method

Tags: javascript, object, this

I have no idea why I get "undefined" instead of the result that should be 32 (2030 - birthYear). Where did I make mistake?

```
const different = {
  macka: "Sofia",
  pes: "Bruno",
  birthYear: 1998,
  number: 14,
  string: "Hello it is a string",
  hasBlueEyes: true,
  calcAge: function () {
    this.age = 2030 - this.birthYear; // in THIS object (different) I create a new age property with the value of "2030 - this.birthYear"
    return this.age;
  }
};

console.log(different.age);
```

Comment: You need to invoke the method first for it to run your code within your function that adds the property

Comment: Hi Nick, I just invoked it before the console.log with ```different.calcAge();``` It worked. Thanks!